# "Using" or "import" clause in eiffel text

Tags: import, using, eiffel

Is there a clause for including/using/import other classes, or maybe that's the Add Library part in EiffelStudio? If so, how would you do it in a text editor based environment?

Comment: If you start using EiffelStudio environment, once the project is compiled, you can browse the included libraries and see what classes are available. When the class is directly or indirectly used in your project, you can also browse the features of this class in various formats. Unless I misunderstand your question, you do not want to use GUI. For this purpose the command-line compiler provides a set of options that are listed in the [Documentation](http://doc.eiffel.com/book/eiffelstudio/eiffelstudio-using-command-line-options).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eiffel there is no equivalent of the C/C++ "include". When you describe your project (in the ecf file) you indicate which clusters and libraries are part of your system. A cluster is basically a folder containing Eiffel classes. When you compile, the Eiffel compiler goes and scans all your clusters/libraries for .e files. You can use all and any of those classes without the need for any "include" directive.

Comment: so the advantage is that you don't clutter the code files with include directives.
yet the ecf file becomes the place where you specify your "library references"? 
something like this line in the xml?:
    <library name="base" location="$ISE_LIBRARY/library/base/base.ecf"/>

Comment: I assume you don't really copy the classes into the cluster folder

Comment: and finally, that sounds quite good, if I understand it correctly. Yet what is the way to find all the features or classes you need?

(All these questions were implied in the original)

Comment: Your reference to the line with `library` in ECF is correct as well as the conclusion that there is no need to copy library classes to the project. But what do you mean by "_find all the features or classes you need_"?

Comment: I just tried to get a hint on how eiffel developers usually work. Is there documentation, some kind of listing index, object browser of some sort... I have yet to explore EiffelStudio in-depth.